# How do I validate a field type in a trigger?

Tags: validation, triggers, salesforce, apex-code

I have a trigger which fires `on Lead (after update)`.  We have an object called Finance which stores some financial information about each lead.  When the trigger fires, it pushes any updates to certain fields into a finance record.  What I have written works great, unless a user decides to input an invalid email, or the record owner is inactive.  An APEX error is thrown, which to most users looks like gibberish and is a little scary.

What I would like to do is check in my trigger whether or not the email is valid so that users don't receive a confusing error.  How can I go about checking whether a field's content is a valid type?  I would like to stay away from using some sort of regex, because there are a couple other fields that I would like to apply this method to, and I'd rather not maintain a list of regex.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could catch the validation error in your trigger:

```
try {
    upsert financeRecord;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // do whatever you'd like to on an exception here
}
```

Comment: So, I'm currently updating 6 fields.  If two of those have improperly formatted data, does `e` hold details about the exception for both of those fields or just the first issue that it hits? Is there a way to display a custom error? I have done some searching on the custom errors, but haven't found anything helpful.

Comment: `e` will only hold info about the first exception. You can display an error on the page. If you want the error to have the default message, add `ApexPages.addMessages(e);` to the controller and add a `<apex:pagemessages />` tag to the page. Otherwise, you could always subclass the Exception class and throw that instead of the default Exception.